# Second parameter is getting the content of the first parameter in shell script function

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I'm creating a function in shell script and I need to pass 2 parameters. One is the path and the another is an array. But the problem is the second parameter is getting the content of the first parameter.

Ex.:

```
input_files_path="./path"
array=("Word1" "Word2" "Word3")

list_files(){
  path=$1
  array_in=("${@}")

  echo "${array_in[@]}"

}

list_files "${input_files_path}" "${array[@]}"
```

Ouput:

```
./path Word1 Word2 Word3
```

If I change the second parameter to

```
array_in=$2
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: This might help: `help shift`

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function with parameters, the fact you assign one parameter to a variable does not remove it form the parameters list.

What you need to do is assign the first parameter to a variable, then use `shift` to remove the argument from the arguments list.  Then when you use `@`, it will no longer include the first parameter.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_files_path="./path"
array=("Word1" "Word2" "Word3")

list_files(){
  path=$1
  # remove the $1 argument from $@
  shift
  array_in=("${@}")

  echo "${array_in[@]}"

}

list_files "${input_files_path}" "${array[@]}"
```